# Вопрос запросов ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем добрый день.

Я только начинаю изучать js и в частности ajax, поэтому просьба отнестись с пониманием.
Мне нужно получить несколько строк таблицы бд. При ajax запросе, как я понимаю, передается только 1 запрос.
У меня есть таблица в которой id элементов 100-500. При клике по элементу, у которого data-* = 100 нужно выводить ВСЕ элементы которые находятся в промежутке id между 100 и 200.
Подкиньте пожалуйста мыслей, куда копать в таком случае.

Скрин кода запроса от бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен!

Comment: никуда не копать. вам нужен все тот же один запрос, который вернет нужные 100 записей

Comment: @teran, получается, мне нужно просто в цикл пихнуть ajax запрос?

Comment: нет. вам нужен всего один запрос.  Другое дело, как вы его обработаете на серверной части. Именно там вы должны выбрать 100 записей и вернуть их.

Comment: @teran, на серверной части стоит запрос к бд по id, которые выполняют условия (меньше 200 например и больше 101). Но в ответ приходит только 1 строчка таблицы.

Comment: Разбирайтесь с кодом серверной части, почему он возвращает всего одну строку если под условие попадают несколько.

Comment: `limit 1` там у вас случаем нет в конце?

Comment: @teran, нет. Лимита не стоит.
Мало ли, может это как то еще даст инфы: сайт сам на wp висит. Может там какие то ограничения есть (но инфы на этот счет не нашел на самом деле).
Спасибо!

Comment: если запросы вбирает нужное число записей, и они отдаются клиенту, а на выходе появляется только одна, значит после получения ответа на клиенте берется только одна запись из полученных. Откройт инструменты разработчика в браузере, посмотрите на вкладке Сеть, что там за запрос у вас отпралвяете, и что приходит в ответ. Поймете на какой стороне искать решение.

Comment: @teran я просто не исключаю возможности не корректного запроса к самой бд, так как, как и говорил, не так давно начал изучать вопрос. Посмотрел в инструментах разработчика, отдает как раз таки одну строку из таблицы. Возможно я таки как то не верно обращаюсь..
http://prntscr.com/uqtujg
Спасибо большое за подсказки

Comment: код из картинки добавьте в вопрос. по сабжу: вы получили массив `$floors` его и отдавайте в `data =>`. Зачем вы делаете `$floor = reset()`, это и есть сброс указателя массива в начало и возврат первого элемента.

Comment: @teran, спасибо огромное! Все заработало!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@teran подсказал ответ на вопрос, за что ему спасибо большое!
В исходном коде была ошибка в написании. $floor = reset() сбрасывало указатель массива в начало.
Без него все работает корректно.